# AttributeError: HMAC instance has no attribute '__len__' python

Tags: amazon-s3, hex, sha256, hmac, attributeerror

currently working on signing a signature for AWS s3. on my last hash where I compute the signature I am getting the following error:

```
 signature = hmac.new(signingkey, policy, hashlib.sha256).digest()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 136, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 71, in __init__
    if len(key) > blocksize:
AttributeError: HMAC instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

the code:

```
datekey = hmac.new(str("AWS4") + AWS_UPLOAD_SECRET_KEY,stringdate , hashlib.sha256).digest()
            dateregionkey = hmac.new(datekey, AWS_UPLOAD_REGION, hashlib.sha256).digest()
            dateregionservicekey = hmac.new(dateregionkey,"s3", hashlib.sha256).digest()
            signingkey = hmac.new(dateregionservicekey, "aws4_request")
            signature = hmac.new(signingkey, policy, hashlib.sha256).digest()
```

any ideas of what is causing this? Always something like this in coding. we get nothing for free -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
signingkey = hmac.new(dateregionservicekey, "aws4_request").digest()
```

otherwise **signingkey**  is a hmac object